# Sending invalid JSON with ConnTest's post

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to test that my endpoint is returning a 400 on invalid JSON. If I do something like this:

```
response = conn
  |> put_req_header("content-type", "application/json")
  |> post(Routes.convert_path(conn, :convert), "invalid JSON")
```

I will get a `Jason.DecodeError` because it's trying to encode my string. How can I get it to not encode it? Looking at the docs it seems it cannot be done:

```
post(conn, path_or_action, params_or_body \\ nil)
```

Is there another way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

```
 test/github_omg_web/controllers/convert_controller_test.exs:36
 ** (Plug.Parsers.ParseError) malformed request, a Jason.DecodeError exception was raised with message "unexpected byte at position 0: 0x61 ('a')"
 code: |> post(Routes.convert_path(conn, :convert), "asdf")
 stacktrace:
   (plug) lib/plug/parsers/json.ex:97: Plug.Parsers.JSON.decode/2
   (plug) lib/plug/parsers.ex:271: Plug.Parsers.reduce/7
   (github_omg) lib/github_omg_web/endpoint.ex:1: GithubOmgWeb.Endpoint.plug_builder_call/2
   (github_omg) lib/github_omg_web/endpoint.ex:1: GithubOmgWeb.Endpoint.call/2
   (phoenix) lib/phoenix/test/conn_test.ex:235: Phoenix.ConnTest.dispatch/5
   test/github_omg_web/controllers/convert_controller_test.exs:40: (test)
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error? I am not sure if the test tries to encode. I believe it is your app trying to *decode*. It might be one of the plugs. What happens if you try to use this endpoint with `curl`?

Comment: @tkowal The problem isn't with the incoming request. It's sending it. Added stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a minimal example to be sure we're on the same page:

```
mix phx.new github_omg
mix ecto.create
mix phx.gen.json Accounts User users name:string
mix ecto.migrate
iex -S mix phx.server
```

To replicate you can paste commands one by one and follow the instructions e.g. (`phx.gen.json` instructs to add `resources "/users", UserController, except: [:new, :edit]` to `scope "/api"` in `lib/github_omg_web/router.ex`.

This is created a fresh project with the same name `github_omg`, a context called `Accounts` and an api endpoint called `localhost:4000/api/users`

Let's perform a malformed request with `curl`:

```
curl --write-out '%{http_code}' --silent -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "Invalid JSON" --output /dev/null localhost:4000/api/users
```

I am using `--silent` and `--output /dev/null` to hide response body. In dev mode it will output entire Phoenix error webpage and clutter the output. `--write-out '%{http_code}` shows http status, `-H` adds headers and `--data` is the invalid JSON we're sending.

The output will be:

```
400
```

so it looks like Phoenix outputs 400 correctly.

In the Phoenix console, we will see:

```
[info] POST /api/users
[debug] ** (Plug.Parsers.ParseError) malformed request, a Jason.DecodeError exception was raised with message "unexpected byte at position 0: 0x49 ('I')"
```

So it looks like under the hood Phoenix automagically converts `ParseError` into 400. Actually, it is not that magical :)

Phoenix computes the error using `Plug.Exception` protocol. Basically, you can throw any exception you like. `defexception` macro allows you to attach custom fields inside exception. Phoenix looks for a field called `plug_status`. `Plug.Parser` defines `ParseError` to return 400.

Back to original question:

You've misread the stack error. The test framework doesn't try to encode the payload. It is your app trying to decode it (and failing). You can read the stack trace backwards:

- tests call endpoint (this is already your app code)
- endpoint calls plug parsers
- this plug throws an exception

This means you have two options:

1. You can skip that test at all. It is not part of your application logic and it might not make sense to test framework you are using.
2. If you really want to make sure (because for example, you are messing with `api` pipeline with custom plugs), instead of checking for 400, you can check if your app rises correct error:

```
    assert_raise Plug.Parsers.ParseError, fn ->
      conn
      |> put_req_header("content-type", "application/json")
      |> post(Routes.convert_path(conn, :convert), "invalid JSON")
    end
```

You test for 400 in conn explicitly only in cases where you set it explicitly.